# How to display time in terminal prompt,using PS1 variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

As we all know, we can modify the "PS1" variable to change the prompt of our terminal on Linux or MAC OS, I have changed "PS1" variable to
`PS1="\[\033[0;37;40m\u@\033[0;36;40m\h:\033[0;35;40m\w$\033[0m^.^\t \]"`, and my prompt of terminal can  display like this.

[image]

the time will be updated after I press "enter" button, now I want to let the time string can update automatically in a single line.How can I do this?I use bash.

Comment: `bash` writes the prompt to standard error, but has no control over it past that point. It cannot go back and edit it.

Comment: What a pity!no way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `zsh` shell
edit `~/.zshrc` adding the following lines:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%B%F{red}%n@%m%f%F{yellow}[%D{%L:%M:%S}]%f:%F{blue}${${(%):-%~}}%f$ %b'
TMOUT=1

TRAPALRM() {
    zle reset-prompt
}
```

Save and then update your terminal with `source .zshrc`

Comment: That's a big "if" for a question tagged `bash`, not `zsh`.

Comment: Yes but in the question wasn't never named bash

Comment: The tags are *part* of the question.

Comment: @JoaoBiriba thank you for your answer, zsh is so powerful, but I use bash , I think I will try zsh. ^.^